# Is There a way to pass a data to my server.js from my client.js because it return a multiple data depend on the client visit my website

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Im trying to return a data from my game.js to my server.js using socket.emit but it return a multiple data depends how many client is online .

`socket.emit('win_num', {winum : numberRes , colorbg : colorbg , hash : hash , rounds : rounds , colorCode:color});`

//This is my socket emit from the client.js using socket.io

// and i will recieve this in my server.js using socket.io and save it to my moggo db unfortunately it become multiple data for example it have a 3 client it will also save 3 data into my monggo db

```
 var myobj = { rounds: data.rounds, hash: data.hash, winnum: data.winum , colors :data.colorbg , colorCode : data.colorCode };

           dbo.collection("game").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
             if (err) throw err;
             console.log("1 document inserted");
             db.close();
            });
```

the result output in the terminal should be " 1 Document inserted "
but the result is 
" 1 Document inserted "
" 1 Document inserted "
" 1 Document inserted "`

Comment: Is it possible to provide more code from client.js?

Comment: If you have three clients running, then all three will send their own copy of the win_num event. The easiest solution to this is, depending on which database library you're using, to use an upsert instead of a normal insert. An upsert will update the existing document in the database if it already exists, therefore preventing duplication.

Comment: Okay i will try that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution to my problem , it is not possible to return a result or data from the client.js unless you do a if statement if the data is duplicate , the solution was to know the result/data before send it to client.js so therefore it will not save depend how many the client is.